# Cannot assign null to a variable

Tags: javascript

```js
const letsMatch = (string, char) => {
  const newRegex = new RegExp(char, "gi");
  let result = string.match(newRegex);
  const findNegIndex = result.indexOf(char);
  if (findNegIndex === null) {
    return result = 0;
  } else {
    if (result.length === 2) {
    const findFirstIndex = fiveT.indexOf(char);
    const findSecondIndex = fiveT.indexOf(char, findFirstIndex + 1);
    result = findSecondIndex - findFirstIndex + 2;
    return result;
  } else {
    return (result = 0);
  }
  }
}

console.log(letsMatch('totititiTo', 'r'))
```

> line 4: const findNegIndex = result.indexOf(char); Throws Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'indexOf').

Comment: because `result` is null, possibly also `fiveT`

Comment: The error means exactly what it says.  `result` is `null`.  What matches do you expect `string.match` to find in this case and why?

Comment: Also: if String.indexOf doesn't find the character it returns -1 not null.

Comment: That's a poor title for this question.  It makes it sound like you are attempting to assign null to a variable and can't do it.  Although indirectly this may be the case that you wish to permit `string.match` to return a null value, your actual problem is that you cannot then unconditionally perform `result.indexOf` because the result may be null.  We must all work under certain conditions -- check our results for errors, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [the documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match), `String.prototype.match()` will return `null` (*not* an empty array) when no matches are found.

And no matches are found.

You can default to an empty array when it returns `null`:

```js
const letsMatch = (string, char) => {
  const newRegex = new RegExp(char, "gi");
  let result = string.match(newRegex) || []; // here
  const findNegIndex = result.indexOf(char);
  if (findNegIndex === null) {
    return result = 0;
  } else {
    if (result.length === 2) {
      const findFirstIndex = fiveT.indexOf(char);
      const findSecondIndex = fiveT.indexOf(char, findFirstIndex + 1);
      result = findSecondIndex - findFirstIndex + 2;
      return result;
    } else {
      return (result = 0);
    }
  }
}

console.log(letsMatch('totititiTo', 'r'))
```

(As an aside, it's not really clear what this function is meant to accomplish, or what you expect `return result = 0` to mean other than `return 0`.  But at the very least the *error* is because you're assuming `string.match` will always return an array, and there exists a use case where it does not.)

Comment: The function should search the string for the two occurrences of the character and return the length between them including the 2 characters. If there are less than 2 or more than 2 occurrences of the character the function should return 0. Removing findNegIndex and just returning result back with a null object if no matches are founding worked.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what you're coding in...

Use ?. - it'll return undefined if result doesn't have that property, and the || will shunt it on over to the null
`const findNegIndex = result?.indexOf(char) || null;`

or

`const findNegIndex = result ? result.indexOf(char) : null;`

I'd also shy away from a variable named "string", for readability's sake - since String.match